# Running Shell Script without a Password Prompt

Tags: freebsd, sudo, shell-scripting

I have a shell script that runs on a **freebsd** OS.
the script has some commands that needs the sudo privileges

Im excuting the script remotley and it's skipping the sudo commands

i tried the following :

```
echo password | sudo -S Command
```

but it's not doing anything (same results)

**note** : i can't modify the sudoers file because it's an automated process that creates a virtual machine and excute the script once it's created

I'm usign posh-ssh to excute the script remotely :

```
#Excute Script 
$ExShellScript = 'echo "password" | sudo -S  sh script.sh 
Write-Output $ExShellScript
$Query2 = $(Invoke-SshCommand -SSHSession $SessionID  -Command $ExShellScript).Output
$Query2 = $Query2.split("`n")
Write-Output $Query2
Remove-SSHSession -Name $SessionID | Out-Null
```

i would apreciate it if someone could guide me to the right direction because im stuck here.

Comment: How about running the _entire_ script as `root`, but _lose privileges_ using `sudo(8)` when `root` isn’t required? This won’t require setting up a proper `sudoers(5)` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you try this :

```
echo "<your_password>" | sudo -S -v
```

after that sudo should will run without asking for a password

[image]

Im suggest you to run the command directly before implement on the remote script to make sure its running well

Comment: Hi @YonzLeon i tried it but i got the same results, for more context i'm using posh-ssh to excute the script remotely i added a screen shot of the code im using

Comment: I see, when im try runing the script remotely its prompt error : `sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper`. It seems running command remotely for sudo priveleges need TTY for password prompt.

solved with flag `-t` when running remote script, ex: `ssh user@host -t "bash script.sh"`

Here my script : `test=$(echo "<sudo-password>" | sudo -S -v  && sudo whoami);`

Comment: Sadly posh-ssh doesn't support pseudo TTY on official repo: https://github.com/darkoperator/Posh-SSH/issues/68 (2015)

You should see this too: https://github.com/darkoperator/Posh-SSH/issues/297

Comment: Hi @ossamaassaghir please vote 'up' if the information helping you